# Populate Textfields based on Multiselect in Listbox in excel Vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column in a worksheet containing list of room numbers (Column A) with its corresponding price (Column E). I have created a list box that pulls all the values from the named column (Column A). I want to populate TextBox1 with the selected rooms and TextBox2 with its corresponding Values from (Column E) separated by ",".

When I select an item, the 2 TextBox automatically populates to the last item in the range
Below is my code

`

```
Private Sub lbxRooms_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

   'Find last row
  LastRow = Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

  Me.lbxSelectedRooms.Clear
  Me.lbxRentPerDay.Clear
  myVar = ""
  myprice = ""
  
  
For X = 0 To Me.lbxRooms.ListCount - 1
    If Me.lbxRooms.Selected(X) Then
    
      myVar = Me.lbxRooms.List(X, 0)
       For i = 2 To LastRow
        
            If myVar = Sheet3.Cells(i, "A") Then
               myVar = Me.lbxRooms.List(X, 0)
               myprice = Sheet3.Cells(i, "E")
            Else
                myVar = myVar & "," & Me.lbxRooms.List(X, 0)
                myprice = myprice & "," & Sheet3.Cells(i, "E")
            End If
        
        Next i
        
    End If
Next X
Me.TextBox1 = myVar
Me.TextBox2 = myprice


End Sub
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is running in the MouseUp event of the listbox - so - every time they select an item, the Textbox is getting populated AND you're clearing their selection, so they can never select two items.  I would have this code in the "AfterUpdate" event - I think - maybe that would let them ctrl-select multiple items and not have code running on every mouse click.

And don't clear the user's selection in this code. You could give them a "clear" button, or just leave it to them to select the correct items.

Comment: I tried it and nothing shows in the TextBox after selection

Comment: Try putting a break-point in the code to ensure it's firing.  If it's not - I would put the code behind a "Calculate" button ... at least to figure out that you have the right code.  Then see if there's an event that will fire it for you automatically.